# Teen accidentally summons evil wizard with missing grandfather's stuff

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book that I read in the early 1990s.

I can't remember if it was a trilogy or just a single book but it starts off with a teen girl and her friends.  Her grandfather mysteriously disappears and she goes to his house to go through his things.

She finds in his basement all these magical items; books, runes, etc and winds up casting a spell that summons this evil wizard who has been watching her since she was little.

Comment: ***Sci-fi*** book? Surely **fantasy** book?

Comment: Maybe it was really advanced science #arthurcclarke ;)